# Python Elasticsearch: How to handle very long query strings

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Consider the following example:

```
NUMBER_KEYWORDS = 3000
es = Elasticsearch("127.0.0.1",port=9200,timeout=120,index="example_index",http_auth=AUTH)
query = {'query': {"bool": { "should": [{"match": {"value.keyword": v}} for v in ["keyword" for i in range(NUMBER_KEYWORDS)]]}}}
es.search(index="example_index", body=query, size=10000)['hits']['hits']
```

this fails with the Exception:

```
RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'failed to create query: [...]
```

whereas it does not fail if I set the `NUMBER_KEYWORDS` keyword to a smaller number (say 1000).

What is a good way to handle very large query strings in the Elasticsearch python interface?

Answer (score 0):

Lucene has a 1024 limit of boolean condition.

You have to change the indices.query.bool.max_clause_count value.

But, you really sure you have to make a such request? Could be better to use array or text for exemple and match on it.

Comment: I am open to any suggestions - What kind of queries would be better to use in this case?

Comment: Detail your context with some short example. How do you store your documents? What kind of keyword are you looking for ? ect ...

Comment: The document have three fields: `key` (string), `value` (string), `content` (list of strings). I have a list of values `lvalues` and I want every document where the `value` field matches one of the values in `lvalues`